# How to post Dynamic list to asp mvc controller

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a models like this:

```
public class Feature
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<keyFeatures> features { get; set; }
}

public class keyFeatures
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

In the Front I dynamically create key  pair values with angular

```
          <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="row">
            <div name="features" class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="{{item.key}}" name="key" ng-model="item.key" />
                   <span class="error" ng-show="$parent.submitted&& innerForm.fieldU.$error.required">Required!</span>
                     </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" name="value" placeholder="enter text..." ng-model="item.value" />
                       <span class="error" ng-show="$parent.submitted && innerForm.userName.$error.required"> Required! </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Iv tried different ways but it always return null to my controller on post (Razor)

```
public ActionResult Create( Feature model)
{
    // ...
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Angular [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service in order to make an asynchronous call to your MVC controller and submit the desired data.

```
var feature = {
    id: 123,
    features: $scope.items
};

$http.post(url, JSON.stringify(feature)).success(function(result) {
    alert('successfully sent to server');
}).error(function() {
    alert('an error occurred');
});
```

In this example I assume that `$scope.items` is an array of objects having the `key` and `value` properties. For example:

```
$scope.items = [
    { key: 'key1', value: 'value1' },
    { key: 'key2', value: 'value2' },
    { key: 'key3', value: 'value3' }
];
```